# I have problems in routing with parameters in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem using the parameters in link. When I try to pass the parameters in link like Link to="/:type" it will have no problem in fetching the rest API and display the list. **But** when my link is like this "/category/:type" like my current link it will give an error and will not display the data. the problem occurs in the componentDidMount in .then(data => this.setState({products: data, isLoading: false}));

```
class Product extends Component {

constructor(props){

    super(props);
    this.state = {products:[],isLoading: true, title : props.match.params.type };


};

async componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    fetch('api/products')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({products: data, isLoading: false}));
};



render() {

    const {products,title,isLoading} = this.state;
    if(isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading....</p>;
    }


    var newTitle =  '';

    if(title === "foodndrinks"){
        newTitle = "Food & Drinks";
    }
    else if(title === "groomingprods"){
        newTitle = "Grooming Products";
    }
    else if(title === "cleaningprods"){
        newTitle = "Cleaning Materials";
    }




    const productList = products.filter(product =>{
        return product.category.categoryName === String(newTitle)

        })
        .map( product=>{
        return <tr key ={product.prodId} >
                    <td>{product.productName}</td>
               </tr>

    });

    return (
        <div>
            <AppNavbar/>
            <Container fluid>


             <Table className="mt-4">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20%">{newTitle}</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {productList} 
                </tbody>
            </Table>
            </Container>
        </div>       
    )

}
```

}

export default Product;

Comment: what does "products" look like? is it an array?

Comment: It is just complaining that `products.filter` is not a function, in other words, are you sure `products` is an array?

Comment: Since you stated that it worked until you click the link, the error might be caused by how you set up the other page or how you manage your data... Your question can be answered better if you provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If error is products.filter is not a function, confirm this by removing this filter, and map all products. this will make you certain if it is routing issue or some other thing is causing a problem.

Comment: please provide more code, assuming products is an array of objects, it appears that you are unintentionally mutation either state or props of your component.

Comment: products is a list... now I know the cause of the problem if my link is like this "/:type" i have no problem but when my link is like this "category/:type" then it will not pick up my rest api. please help